# return a list from class object

Tags: pandas, python-multiprocessing

I am using multiprocessing module to generate 35 dataframes. I guess this will save my time. But the problem is that the class does not return anything. I expect the list of dataframes to be returned from self.dflist

Here is how to create dfnames list.

```
urls=[]
fnames=[]
dfnames=[]
for x in xrange(100,3600,100):
    y = str(x)
    i = y.zfill(4)
    filename='DCHB_Town_Release_'+i+'.xlsx'
    url = "http://www.censusindia.gov.in/2011census/dchb/"+filename
    urls.append(url)
    fnames.append(filename)
    dfnames.append((filename, 'DCHB_Town_Release_'+i))
```

This is the class that uses the dfnames generated by above code.

```
import pandas as pd
import multiprocessing
class mydf1():
    def __init__(self, dflist, jobs, dfnames):
        self.dflist=list()
        self.jobs=list()
        self.dfnames=dfnames
    def dframe_create(self, filename, dfname):
        print 'abc', filename, dfname
        dfname=pd.read_excel(filename)
        self.dflist.append(dfname)
        print self.dflist
        return self.dflist

    def mp(self):
        for f,d in self.dfnames:
            p = multiprocessing.Process(target=self.dframe_create, args=(f,d))
            self.jobs.append(p)
            p.start()
        #return self.dflist

        for j in self.jobs:
            j.join()
            print '%s.exitcode = %s' % (j.name, j.exitcode)
```

This class when called like this...

```
dflist=[]
jobs=[]
x=mydf1(dflist, jobs, dfnames)
y=x.mp()
```

Prints the self.dflist correctly. But does not return anything.

I can collect all datafarmes sequentially. But in order to save time, I need to use multiple processes simultaneously to generate and add dataframes to a list.

Answer (score 3):

In your case I prefer to write as less code as possible and use `Pool`:

```
import pandas as pd
import logging
import multiprocessing

def dframe_create(filename):
    try:
         return pd.read_excel(filename)
    except Exception as e:
         logging.error("Something went wrong: %s", e, exc_info=1)
         return None

p = multiprocessing.Pool()

excel_files = p.map(dframe_create, dfnames)
for f in excel_files:
      if f is not None:
            print 'Ready to work'
      else:
            print ':('
```

Comment: How do I know if the process is completed successfully? Is there similar method like j.exitcode shown in the question?

Comment: @shantanuo, Process will raise a exception if something happen with it, but it's rare event. Exception in `dframe_create` function is most likely, so, you can add `try-except` and check result for `None`. I made some changes in my answer to show this method of approach.

Answer (score 2):

> Prints the self.dflist correctly. But does not return anything.

That's because you don't have a return statement *in the `mp` method*, e.g.

```
def mp(self):
    ...
    return self.dflist
```

It's not entirely clear what you're issue is, however, you have to take some care here in that you can't just pass objects/lists across processes. That's why you have special objects (which lock while they make modifications to a list), that way you don't get tripped up when two processes try to make a change at the same time (and you only get one update).

That is, you have to use [multiprocessing's list](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.managers.SyncManager.list).

```
class mydf1():
    def __init__(self, dflist, jobs, dfnames):
        self.dflist = multiprocessing.list()  # perhaps should be multiprocessing.list(dflist or ())
        self.jobs = list()
        self.dfnames = dfnames
```

However you have a bigger problem: the whole point of multiprocessing is that they may run/finish out of order, so keeping two lists like this is doomed to fail. You should use a [multiprocessing.dict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.managers.SyncManager.dict) that way the DataFrame is saved unambiguously with the filename.

```
class mydf1():
    def __init__(self, dflist, jobs, dfnames):
        self.dfdict = multiprocessing.dict()
        ...

    def dframe_create(self, filename, dfname):
        print 'abc', filename, dfname
        df = pd.read_excel(filename)
        self.dfdict[dfname] = df
```